# In IBM Connections can you retrieve another users activity feed?

Tags: android-activity, stream, connection

In IBM Connections 4.0 is there any way to get another users activity stream. I can get my steam with @me but if I try my connections id or another users id I get the following error:

This works:

```
  /opensocial/basic/rest/activitystreams/@me/@following/@all?rollup=true
```

This returns an error - my id:

```
/opensocial/basic/rest/activitystreams/7AF0B251-9F97-CA6D-8525-61370072A674/@following/@all?rollup=true
```

Error 400: The user ID(s) [7AF0B251-9F97-CA6D-8525-61370072A674] is/are not recognized by the system.

And I know this is my ID....

```
<userid>7AF0B251-9F97-CA6D-8525-61370072A674</userid>
```

Any suggestions...the manual says the following which doesn't sound good but doesn't totally close the door either:

As per the OpenSocial standard, a given users Activity Stream is retrievable by:
1. Specifying that user (@me in the URLs below, IBM Connections does not ***generally allow*** retrieval of other users streams).

Any help would be appreciated....

Answer (score 1):

This should do it:  https://connections.ibm.com/common/opensocial/basic/rest/activitystreams/urn:lsid:lconn.ibm.com:profiles.person:91ae7240-8f0a-1028-8400-db07163b51b2/@involved/@all?rollup=true&shortStrings=true&format=atom  (plug in the right user id)

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion...it is providing information but is not the activity feed that I'm looking for. I did try this:

    /connections/opensocial/basic/rest/activitystreams/urn:lsid:lconn.ibm.com:profiles.person:7AF0B251-9F97-CA6D-8525-61370072A674/@following/@all?rollup=true

But I get the same error message:

    Error 400: The user ID&#40;s&#41; [urn:lsid:lconn.ibm.com:profiles.person:7AF0B251-9F97-CA6D-8525-61370072A674] is/are not recognized by the system.

Any other suggestions? Is this a limitation of this REST API? We have opened a PMR with IBM.